# Why wrapper around component doesn't see validate method in v-form via ref? (vuetify v-form)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I've created a component which contains v-form:

MyForm.vue

```
<v-form v-model="valid">
  // custom form
</v-form>
```

Now when I use it in my view MyFormView.vue like that:

```
<MyForm v-model="isValid" ref="myForm"/>
```

I can't access the *validate()* method via ref.

```
validateForm() {
  this.$refs.myForm.validate(); // this doesn't work
}
```

Why is that?